# I am having trouble linking the Firebase Simple Login Framework to my project with an "Undefined symbols for architecture i386: error"

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

I am having trouble linking the Firebase Simple Login Framework to my project with an "Undefined symbols for architecture i386: error"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your picture, you are trying to use FB Login but haven't yet installed the Facebook SDK.  Check out developer.facebook.com and sign up.  Once you connect that to your project, it should run fine.  The simple login is dependent on classes from this SDK to utilize facebook login.  When it can't find them, your project crashes.

Comment: Given that OP refers to Firebase, FB could well stand for Firebase in this case. Could the cause be the same: Firebase SDK not installed?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - Firebase prefixes all of their classes with 'F' the classes he needs are definitely facebook.  I've used both sdk's fairly extensively.

Comment: Thanks for checking. It looks like OP indeed solved the problem with your help.